# Fit Image to PictureBox if PictureBox is smaller than Picture

Tags: c#, image, winforms, picturebox

I have a `PictureBox` that can have multiple different sizes (depends on screen resolution, window state, etc.). What I would like is to fit my `image` to the `PictureBox` when either of the `image` dimensions (width or height) goes below the respective dimension of the `PictureBox`.

***Example:*** If the width of the `image` is greater than that of the `PictureBox`, but the height of the `image` is less than that of the `PictureBox`, it will resize the `image` width until it equals that of the `PictureBox`, maintaining the original aspect ratio, and center the `image` vertically.

If the `PictureBox` is larger than both `image` dimensions, then the image is simply centered. That part I have done with `PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize` and some code to center the `image` based on the sizes of the `image` and `PictureBox`.

```
picbx.ImageLocation = "Image path here";
picbx.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
picbx.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
picbx.Location = new Point((picbx.Parent.ClientSize.Width / 2) - (picImage.Width / 2),
                           (picbx.Parent.ClientSize.Height / 2) - (picImage.Height / 2));
picbx.Refresh();
```

One thing I do not need to account for is resizing in the moment. The window does not allow for resizing and there's no need to account for any other situation other than initial load.

I have found many posts that seem to hit close but nothing that fully works. **Stretch** skews the `image`, **AutoSize** does not resize based on container size, and **Zoom** may work fine for when the `image` is larger than the `PictureBox` but I've yet to discover a way to prevent zoom from increasing the `image` size to fit the `PictureBox`.

Because I'm setting it to an `picbx.ImageLocation` and not setting the `picbx.Image` property, I've yet to figure out a way to resize the `image` inside of the `PictureBox` based on the dimension (width or height) that needs to be the reference for resizing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you know the `PictureBox` and `Image` sizes, you can simply set the appropriate `SizeMode` - `Zoom` when width or height of the image is bigger than the picture box, `CenterImage` otherwise:

```
var imageSize = picbx.Image.Size;
var fitSize = picbx.ClientSize;
picbx.SizeMode = imageSize.Width > fitSize.Width || imageSize.Height > fitSize.Height ?
    PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom : PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Just needed the right combination. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to set the Zoom to fit a specific dimension instead of the default way? Like if I wanted to switch so it zooms to the width instead of the height as to mimic a sort of zoom?

Comment: I don't think so. It scales to fit both dimensions, still keeping the original image proportions, which make sense. What do you mean to fit a specific dimension? Fit one and cut the other?

Comment: I figured a way for my situation to work. What I meant was to fit one and force a scroll bar for the other. But I figured out something that functions